# Scikit-Learn Wrappers for tensorflow not working with Celery-Redis

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, redis, celery

I am trying to run a server to train neural networks based on user input.
I am using the sklearn wrappers for tensorflow to create the neural networks. Running Redis as the message broker with celery to train the models using:

`celery -A neural_networks_task worker --pool gevent -l info`

When I try to train the model, I am met with this error:

`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.`

Comment: What is your tensorflow version? It seems that you need to support eager mode like tf.compat.v1.enable_ eager_ execution()

Comment: I'm running tf 2.4. I checked if eager execution was enabled using ```tf.executing_eagerly()``` and it returned True. But it's still giving me the same error.